# Linq - get unavailable IDs in a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a ID list as "100,1025,5341" and a objects list. I want to get the IDs which are not include in my object list.

as an example, lets assume that objects list contains both 100 and 5341 as a property (eg: ID). I want to get 1025 as my result. I know that this request make no sense but i want to get that somehow. I can easily use,

```
string idList = "100,1025,5341";
var objectList = _dataService.GetData();
var result = objectList.Any(item=> idList.Contains(item.ID));
```

to get the list items which are having given IDs. But i want get other way. I want get the IDs which are not exists in the list.

Comment: @elgonzo can i get only "1025" (according to my example) as the result?

Comment: Query your idList with Linq, not the objectList. (objectList does not have an item with id 1025, hence querying objectList will never give you 1025, because it is not in it...) Turn the idList string into an array/list first. Use `.Where` instead of `.Any` (read MSDN documentation to figure out why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Except`:

```
var ids= idList.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
var result = objectList.Where(item=> ids.Contains(item.ID));
var r= objectList.Except(result);
```

If you want only the ids that are not include in your object list, then you can do the following

```
 var ids= idList.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
 var r= ids.Except(ids.Where(i=> objectList.Any(item=> item.ID==i)));
```

Comment: @octavioccl Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It will get you Ids from `idList` which are not Ids of `objectList`. If I undestood correctly what you want...

```
var ids = objectList.Select(x=>x.ID).ToList();
var otherIdsList = idList.Split(',').Select(x=>int.Parse(x)).ToList().Where(x=> !ids.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, i made a mistake here. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: As long as it helps ;)